# What could cause a slowdown of reports in MS Access when linking to an SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, reporting

I am moving an Access application's tables from an Access file to a SQL Server. The original application had a front end file with a data file it linked to. The data file lived on a network drive. I am now linking the front end file to a SQL Server using an ODBC connection.

All the forms appear to work. However, there are two reports that are painfully slow. In the old configuration, the reports would load up in a couple seconds.

However, in the new version they can take minutes. These reports consist of multiple sub-reports that have their own datasets along with the main report's dataset. I have gone through each query and tweaked it so that it takes less than a second for each query to run. However, I still have the delay when I try to run the overall report.

I have worked with linked tables quite a bit. However, reporting on the access side is fairly new to me. Is there any reason the reports would be slower with the linked tables compared to a linked file? Is there a good practice concerning sub reports in reporting that might speed up the load time?

Comment: Can you create a VIEW in SQLServer that limits the data returned? Do you have any local tables that may be included in your existing query? You want to try and limit the data transferred across the net.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. And I think I might implement the view solution, good idea. However, I am still confused as to why the report loads slower than the previous configuration. The file that contained the data was still on a network drive and was only an accdb file. It still had to go over the net without the benefit of the SQL server software.  Why would the previous configuration still be faster?

Comment: Way back in 2000 I worked on an Access project that involved getting data from an ODBC connection that was not Microsoft related (I think it was an IBM midrange platform). Performance was VERY bad! I enabled a trace of the command interface and it was insane! A simple query generated over 100 pages of trace log. PC: Hello; IBM: Hello; PC: I have a request; IBM: OK; PC: want fld1; IBM: Really?;  on and on! If you join server table to local table, it must transfer ALL the data to the PC to sort out. You want the server to do the work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can occur quite often. The reason of course is that when using Access with a JET/ACE (file back end), then the application can make “better” choices about how to join data.

When you use SQL server, then the main report and the sub reports are viewed by Access as separate tables from separate data sources. So Access often does a rather poor job of joining the data together. And toss in the fact that reports often requery and reload parts of data many times (more often than one would like), then shortcomings in how Access pulls data from SQL server really show up. (Access has a hard time joining the parent tables to the child tables in the sup-reports).

The most simple (and least amount of changes) is to the change the query used for the main reports (and the sub reports) to views on the sql server. You then link to those views from Access (they show up as standard tables in Access). You then based the main report on this view (as opposed to the query). And do the same for the sub-reports. This approach is not the best, but it should improve things dramatically, especially if the main report is a query that joins multiple tables, and also if the sub reports are also based on queries that are based on multiple tables.

The above is the least amount of work, since then filters and where clauses etc. used on the reports should continue to function without changes to your front end application.